# public ids in relationships for REST API

Tags: rest, orm, relation

I'm building a REST API, some of the resources have relationship between them. What are pro and cons of exposing database ids? One that comes to mind is that if their are auto increment you can expose some unwanted data (if number x exist, then there could have existed also x-1)

I googled extensively for best practices in this scenario but didn't really find out a reference guide.

Should ids (of records or of relationships) be exposed? If not, what is the current standard format for public ids? uuid4? The setup uses ORM to abstract the database, but if that helps it may end up being postgre in production.

Thanks